# Adding individual values to a count query

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have the query below that returns a count of a number of tickets.  I also want the query to return the individual ticket numbers in the count.
This is the query:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
select SR_Service_RecID 
from SR_Audit 
where Audit_Text like 'Ticket status has been changed from % to "Internal"%' OR
      Audit_Text like 'Ticket status has been changed from % to "Closed"%' OR
      Audit_Text like 'Ticket status has been changed from % to "First Contact Resolution"%'
)
SELECT Board_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT A.SR_Service_RecID) AS 'Re-Opened Tickets'
FROM CTE 
JOIN SR_Audit A 
  ON CTE.SR_Service_RecID = A.SR_Service_RecID  
JOIN v_rpt_service vsrv 
  ON vsrv.TicketNbr = A.SR_Service_RecID
WHERE Audit_Text LIKE 'Ticket status has been changed from%"Re-Opened"%'
  AND vsrv.company_name <> 'XYZ Test Company' 
  AND vsrv.date_entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
  AND Board_Name in (@BoardName)
GROUP BY Board_Name
```

It returns:

```
Board Name    Count
IT Services     4
```

I want it to return this:

```
 Board Name    Count    Ticket Number
 IT Services    4         12346
 IT Services    4         12445
 IT Services    4         56345
 IT Services    4         12384
```

How can I add the ticket numbers to the result?

Comment: can you show us some sample data to generate that result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wont try to understand the whole query, but you need use window functions.

A simplify version for your case would be:

```
 SELECT [BoardName],
        COUNT([Ticket Number]) Over (PARTITION BY [BoardName]) as [Count],
        [Ticket Number]
 FROM YourBoardTable
```

The `PARTITION BY [BoardName]` will do the trick and you wont need `GROUP BY`

**Option B:** You calculate the total and then JOIN back to original query

```
WITH cte as ( 
     --Same as your current CTE
), filter as (
        SELECT Board_Name, 
               DISTINCT A.SR_Service_RecID AS 'Re-Opened Tickets'
        FROM CTE  ....
        -- Your filter query without COUNT / GROUP BY
), cnt as (
      SELECT [BoardName],
             COUNT([Re-Opened Tickets]) as COUNT
      FROM filter 
      GROUP BY [BoardName]
)
SELECT F.[BoardName],
       C.[Count],
       F.[Ticket Number]
FROM filter F
JOIN cnt C
  ON Y.[BoardName] = C.[BoardName]
```

**Option C:** with filter you now can use window function3

```
 SELECT [BoardName],
        COUNT([Re-Opened Tickets]) Over (PARTITION BY [BoardName]) as [Count],
        [Ticket Number]
 FROM filter
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  The results are closer but still not correct.  I need to use the `DISTINCT` keyword in the `COUNT` function but that is not allowed when using `PARTITION`

Comment: That is why is always nice include some sample data so we can test it.

Comment: There is a lot of data.  I found something about using max function and dense_rank with Partition but still researching it.

Comment: Check option B. again simplify version ;)

Comment: I'm afraid that will not work either.  I use the CTE to get a set of tickets that have been 'closed' from one table.  These are not the tickets that I want to count.  i need to count the tickets that have been reopened which is the SELECT query and the counts.

Comment: That isnt a problem, you calculate that `SELECT` name it cte2, and do my `SELECT` using that one instead. easy cake. Again if you create a working sample in [rextester](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler) I will show you.

Comment: I don't understand.  I use my CTE first, then create a second CTE (cte2) to calculate the count then join it to the table to get the individual tickets?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean

Comment: More precise... You calculate your big `SELECT` without `GROUP BY`, call it `cte2`. with that you use my query to create `cte3` the one with count, Then using my `SELECT` you `JOIN` `cte2` and `cte3` as I did in the last part.

Comment: THAT WORKED!...You're a genius!  Thanks so much!

Comment: I was just updating with the changes to make my point more clear.  But looks like you got it.

Comment: putting `DISTINCT` on filter cte you can now use window function and save one step.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
select SR_Service_RecID 
from SR_Audit 
where Audit_Text like 'Ticket status has been changed from % to "Internal"%' OR
  Audit_Text like 'Ticket status has been changed from % to "Closed"%' OR
  Audit_Text like 'Ticket status has been changed from % to "First Contact Resolution"%'
)
SELECT cte.SR_Service_RecID,Board_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT A.SR_Service_RecID) AS 'Re-Opened Tickets'
FROM CTE 
JOIN SR_Audit A 
 ON CTE.SR_Service_RecID = A.SR_Service_RecID  
JOIN v_rpt_service vsrv 
 ON vsrv.TicketNbr = A.SR_Service_RecID
WHERE Audit_Text LIKE 'Ticket status has been changed from%"Re-Opened"%'
 AND vsrv.company_name <> 'XYZ Test Company' 
 AND vsrv.date_entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate 
 AND Board_Name in (@BoardName)
GROUP BY cte.SR_Service_RecID,Board_Name
```